# Как найти подвисающий тест

Tags: юнит-тесты, tfs

Для решения настроена автоматическая сборка в TFS 2017 при помощи build agent. Периодически она отваливается по таймауту на шаге запуска модульных тестов.
Но вот как определить этот самый зависающий-тест?

В логе пишется лишь результат прохождения теста, но не факт начала его запуска. Поэтому пока найти сломаный тест - не получается.

Comment: Локально-то пробовали запускать, прямо в Студии?

Comment: Пробовали. Баг плавающий. Поймать пока не получилось. А как я уже сказал по логам сборки тоже не видно, какой тест начал исполняться но не закончился